# VBA Script to Create PDF from Excel Goes to Printer and Doesn't Export File

Tags: excel, vba, macos, pdf, export

I have the following code which worked well on a Windows machine but since I moved to a MacBook, it is causing me problems:

```vb
With ActiveSheet
  Fname = "SalarySlip-" + employeeName + "-" + month + ".pdf"

  .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, fileName:= _
    salarySlipsFolderPath & Fname, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, 

  OpenAfterPublish:=False
End With
```

Rather than exporting as a PDF file (it worked like that on Windows), a request is sent to the printer to print the file. What am I missing here?

I am using MacOS Catalina 10.15.4 running MS Excel for MAC version 16.40.

Comment: Try manually exporting the file as PDF and record the macro, you can take the recorded code and use it in you actual code.

Comment: @usmanhaq I tried that but macro recording did not capture the export process. I tried the COMMAND + P shortcut as well going into print menu through the File menu.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52473104/save-as-pdf-using-mac-excel-vba

Comment: I don't have a Mac to try this on, but I wonder if this sheds any light: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63722008

Comment: try setting ```Application.PrintCommunication = False``` before your code and then back to True after.

Comment: I would first of all set the full path of the dir, then checking if the OS has set a default behavior to open PDF files. Link provided by @niton could be usefull in this context. Btw i don't understand why it prints it instead anyway....it could be cause of the working directory anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If one cell value you're using as a variable includes slashes (for example the date in `month` as 2020/01/01), the naming process of the PDF file fails and it sends it out to the printer. I had that for several desperate hours...

And try

```
ChDir "/" & ActiveWorkbook.Path
```

as first line in the `Sub` and

```
fileName:= _
    "/" & salarySlipsFolderPath & Fname, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
```

as filename. The `"/"` at the beginning made it working for me.